# programmatically change the "managed" option of a migration

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a Django application that has a model like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tick

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tick = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    name2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'company'
```

When I executed `python manage.py makemigrations` this migration was created:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='Company',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
        ('tick', models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)),
        ('name', models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)),
        ('name2', models.CharField(max_length=128)),
    ],
    options={
        'db_table': 'company',
        'managed': False,
    },
)
```

For some reason I want to change the `'managed'` field in this migration to `True` programmatically, something like this:

```
migrations.change_option('Company', 'managed', True)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: "Is this possible?" no

Comment: Can't you just edit the value to `'managed': True` in the migration file?

Comment: @Alasdair: No I want to do it somewhere in my code.

Comment: Sorry not answering your question. What does that "managed" actually means / do?

Comment: @François It means that django does not create or delete this table.

Comment: Thanks @Navid777. Ah OK, so what about changing your model too BUT you could run `migrate --fake`. Would that solve your problem?